# Creating non clustered index of a nullable bit, error on syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my SQL:

```
Create nonclustered index ixtable on table (isdeleted)
  where isdeleted is null
  or isdeleted = 0
```

`isdeleted` is nullable bit column with default constraint 0.

The above command causes error:

> incorrect syntax near null and near OR.

This table is left joined 3 times where `isdeleted` which shows records that have `isdeleted` is null or 0. I am trying to tune the select by creating this index so that I don't have to explicitly put a sargable where clause condition.

What is wrong with the syntax?

I tried removing default constraint, but it did not work.

Removing the `isdeleted is null` seems to work, but I need it.

Comment: Try `where coalesce(isdeleted, 0) = 0`?

Comment: `NONCLUSTERED`, without spaces

Comment: According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  `OR` is not listed under  `<filter_predicate>`

Comment: @Bohemian it says incorrect syntax near coalesce

Comment: @Squirrel what is the alternative?

Comment: @siggemannen you can't filter an index on a computed column. that was my first thought as well...

Comment: @ZoharPeled oh no! Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: *"I am trying to tune the select by creating this index so that I don't have to explicitly put a sargable where clause condition."* The term "sargable" means a condition that the database can use an index to speed up the search. For more information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: The alternative is you create two seperate filtered indexes each with a term of the OR. I have found SQL Server is smart enough to use both indexes seperately and combine them. For your data, is there a difference between NULL and 0? If not just update all NULL's to zero and have a simpler index

Comment: @ZoharPeled An indexed view would work though

Comment: @Charlieface Not a filtered index....  Filtered indexes are only supported on tables. https://dbfiddle.uk/Lb-KlaC7

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's not an indexed view, this is https://dbfiddle.uk/spE7Czso I was saying to make a *normal* index on the view

Comment: Worth noting though that unless the majority of the rows are deleted then this index on it's own is unlikely to be of much use except for counts as any select is going to require a bookmark lookup, and chances are the nonclustered index seek + Bookmark lookup will be more expensive than just a clustered index scan. In a quick test I found that the index wasn't used until only 99.842% of rows were deleted ([Index not used](https://dbfiddle.uk/G1tVI71Z) vs [Index used](https://dbfiddle.uk/h3_H58wj)).

Comment: The exact numbers will vary by scenario, but you almost certainly need some non-key columns in this index to make it useful, but at that point if the majority of the rows are not deleted you're creating a lot of overhead for probably not a lot of performance gain. This might be more useful as a filter on other indexes that are required, but as I say, the index as presented is probably not going to be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to define two different indexes, one filtered by `IsDeleted = 0` and one filtered by `IsDeleted IS NULL`.

SQL Server could use both indexes under certain circumstances, at the condition that the filter doesn't overlap. However SQL Server may not always use the filtered indexes for your query, depending on the query optimizer decision.

I do a little test defining a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    Id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY ,
    IsDeleted BIT NULL);


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test ON Test(IsDeleted)
WHERE IsDeleted IS NULL;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_2 ON Test(IsDeleted)
WHERE IsDeleted = 0;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;

-- Iniziare un ciclo while per inserire 20000 righe
WHILE @Counter <= 30000
BEGIN
    -- Inserire una riga con Id progressivo e IsDeleted casuale
    INSERT INTO Test (Id, IsDeleted)
    VALUES (@Counter, CHOOSE(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 + 1, 0, 1, NULL));

    -- Incrementare il contatore di 1
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END;
```

When I perform a `COUNT(*)` operation the system uses both indexes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEst WHERE ISDeleted = 0 OR ISDeleted IS NULL
```

This is the resulting query plan [image: Query Plan for COUNT(*)]

Comment: That is quite a cumbersome solution, considering the fact that the `IsDeleted` column should probably not be nullable in the first place (A record can either be deleted or not, using `null` here sends it into a sort of Limbo state (or a quantum superposition, if you prefer) where it's neither deleted nor undeleted, and at the same time, both deleted and undeleted. 
Changing the column to a non-nullable bit will simplify everything, including all queries referencing this column. 
It doesn't mean this can't be applied in other situations, just that it's not ideal for this one.

Comment: I agree that the best solution is to set IsDeleted as not nullable with a default of zero. But as you suggested I think it could be an option that could be used in other use cases.

Answer (score 2):

The filter part of filtered indexes in SQL server has some strict conditions about what operators and operands it allows.
You can only compare columns with constants, and use a very limited set of comparison or logical operators:
`column_name IN (constant ,...n)`
Or
`column_name <comparison_op> constant`
where `<comparison_op>` is one of the following:
`IS, IS NOT, =, <>. !=, >, >=, !>, <, <=, !<`
You can combine conditions with `AND`, but not with `OR` - so something like
`WHERE column > 5 AND column < 10` is valid,
but `WHERE column IS NULL OR column = 0` is not valid.

Also, the column used in the filter can't be a computed column, a UDT column, a spatial data type column, or a hierarchyID data type column.

However, you can alter the table to make your `isdeleted` column a non-nullable column (you already have a default value of `0`, so that's not a problem), and then it's quite easy to add the computed index you wanted:

```
-- change all null values to 0;
UPDATE table
SET isdeleted = 0 
WHERE isdeleted IS NULL;

-- make the column non-nullable
ALTER TABLE table
    ALTER COLUMN isdeleted bit NOT NULL;

-- create filtered index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixtable 
    ON table (isdeleted)
    WHERE isdeleted = 0;
```

Comment: Depending on the size and mutation velocity of the table, the first two steps might not be practical. You could add a new non-nullable column with default that will hold the data (say `isdeleted_new`) and a trigger to keep it in sync with respect to the existing column. Once the backfill is complete, you can rename isdeleted to isdeleted_old and isdeleted_new to isdeleted. FWIW, I also like to add an isMigrated column when I'm doing these sorts of things which is set both by the backfill and the trigger.

Comment: @BenThul good point.